# AngularJS calling Directive function with or without parameter from Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have search a lot on Internet, but i did not found any good example for what i am looking. It may be due to i am new in angularjs.

What i am looking, I have some common function which i need to fire on different situation from controller or may be from different directive, within directive or any matter.

right not i am having two situation, 1) on focusin and focusout i want to give border to its parent wrapper for this i am writing these functions:

```
module.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {        
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){  
      scope.focusIn = function($event){
        angular.element($event.target).parent().addClass('focus');
      }
      scope.focusOut = function($event){
        angular.element($event.target).parent().removeClass('focus');
      }
});
```

Now, the question is how can i call these function from html code like i am having html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" my-directive="focusin($event)">
</div>
```

As, above code is not working.

Now the second question is similar to above. I have created a module for password strength. Where i am checking the password strength. this directive i working fine, but i am not able to call this directive function from one of my controller.

```
module.directive("passwordStrength", function(){
    var strongRegex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
    var mediumRegex = new RegExp("^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})");
    return {        
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){  
          scope.$watch(attrs.passwordStrength, function(value) {
              if(angular.isDefined(value)){
                  if(strongRegex.test(value)) {
                      scope.strength = 'strong';
                  } else if(mediumRegex.test(value)) {
                      scope.strength = 'medium';
                  } else {
                      scope.strength = 'weak';
                      scope.loginForm.$invalid = true;
                  }
              }
          });
        }
    };
});
<input type="password" placeholder="••••••" class="input-field clearfix password" ng-focus="focusIn($event)" password-strength="focusOut($event)" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" name="password" ng-model="loginData.password" required password-strength="loginData.password">
```

Above code is working fine for password strength, but i want to call above code in user submit the form and `ng-submit` function should call the password strength function. Please help me in this regards.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8PRZhNvdOEBxGz5iN1fP?p=preview)

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: My plunkr not saving...

Comment: what you mean _not saving_? so save it :-)

Comment: Actually i am creating, but plunkr not save so that i can share here. But now i have created please look and suggest me the resolution.

Comment: i'm a bit confused with you plunkr and post: your code have too many diffrence. can you reduce all not relevant part?

Comment: is this what you want? http://plnkr.co/edit/z4nhyoqgg3fdqPSnp3lo?p=preview

Comment: I have removed unwanted code. Please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93980/discussion-between-grundy-and-mandy).

Comment: Yes, It is but i am also want when i have not enter any thing and click on submit, then password strength function should call. Like i have comment the line in submit() function. i have to call that function from there too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your questions correctly;

ad 1) you can use the jQuery element `element` in your `link` function to capture events on the directive's element:

```
element.focus(function(event, args) {
   element.parent().addClass('focus');
});

element.blur(function(event, args) {
    element.parent().removeClass('focus');
});
```

ad 2) I suggest you move the code of your `passwordStrength` function into a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and call the function using `ng-change` on your input element.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**  Here is the basic version of dom directive which set background color on focus.

```
.directive('domDirective', function () {
      return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
              element.on('focus', function () {
                  element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
              });
              element.on('blur', function () {
                  element.css('background-color', 'white');
              });
          }
      };
  });
```

You can follow this [Plunker](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epjJmb) to see it in action.

2) My suggestion would be as stated in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/migontech/3QRDt/1/)